# KDB+ How to join data for particular dates

Tags: left-join, kdb

I have the following table containing some time-series data about some countries:

```
t1 : ([]dates:"d"$4+til 6) cross ([]country:`PT`AR`MR`LT; category1:1+til 4)

 dates      country category1
----------------------------
2000.01.05 PT      1        
2000.01.05 AR      2        
2000.01.05 MR      3        
2000.01.05 LT      4        
2000.01.06 PT      1        
2000.01.06 AR      2        
2000.01.06 MR      3        
2000.01.06 LT      4        
2000.01.07 PT      1        
2000.01.07 AR      2        
2000.01.07 MR      3        
2000.01.07 LT      4                 
..
```

I have another table containing some complementary data for `t1`, but that are only valid from a certain point in time, as follows:

```
t2 : (([]validFrom:"d"$(0;6)) cross ([]country:`PT`AR`MR`LT)),'([]category2:1000*(1+til 8)) 

validFrom  country category2
----------------------------
2000.01.01 PT      1000     
2000.01.01 AR      2000     
2000.01.01 MR      3000     
2000.01.01 LT      4000     
2000.01.07 PT      5000     
2000.01.07 AR      6000     
2000.01.07 MR      7000     
2000.01.07 LT      8000
```

My question is: how do I join `t1` and `t2` to get the `category2` column only for `dates` in `t1` that are "compliant" with the `validFrom` dates in `t2`, such that the resulting table would look like this:

```
dates      country category1 category2
--------------------------------------
2000.01.05 PT      1         1000     
2000.01.05 AR      2         2000     
2000.01.05 MR      3         3000     
2000.01.05 LT      4         4000     
2000.01.06 PT      1         1000     
2000.01.06 AR      2         2000     
2000.01.06 MR      3         3000     
2000.01.06 LT      4         4000     
2000.01.07 PT      1         5000     
2000.01.07 AR      2         6000     
2000.01.07 MR      3         7000     
2000.01.07 LT      4         8000        
..
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [asof](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/) join to get the most recent `category2` from `t2` by date

```
aj[`country`dates;t1;`dates xasc `dates xcol t2]
```

Just don't forget to rename `validFrom` column to `dates` in table 2 and sort it by `dates`